# How do I draw separators?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, separator

I am programming in C, using the Windows API, and would like to know how I could draw *separators*. I would appreciate a code example.

Edit: Here's an illustration.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC60502.png))</sub>

Comment: I said I'm writing a GUI application. You see these lines separating our comments? Those basically :)

Comment: Are you talking about separators in *menus*? (Notepad's Edit menu: Undo/Separator/Cut/Copy/Paste/Delete/Separator/Find/Find Next/...) Or are you talking about separators in flat *toolbars*? (New/Open/Save/Separator/Undo/Redo/Separator/...)

Comment: Separators like the ones seen in IE or Firefox, where they are used to separate the menu from the buttons, the buttons from the bookmarks toolbar etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a static control/window with the [SS_ETCHEDHORZ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h0ay857.aspx) style (This is what explorer does and should give you the most accurate rendering when it comes to Visual Styles)

Comment: I believe that is for MFC. I'm using Win32, but maybe I can look into MFC.

Comment: No, the static control is a normal native win32 control

Answer (score 2):

I don't suppose you're just looking for `LineTo`?

For menus and toolbars, generally the separators are drawn for you by the menu and toolbar APIs. For random separators in dialog boxes, etc, like in the picture you added you can just draw a line.

Comment: Owner draw is overkill when there is a common control that does exactly what you want (And you don't have to handle Classic vs Visual styles etc)

Answer (score 2):

OK, you just want to draw straight lines on the form. That is trivial. When drawing your window, i.e. when processing the [WM_PAINT message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922583.aspx), simply draw a line using the [MoveToEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145069(VS.85).aspx) and [LineTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145029(VS.85).aspx) functions.

Answer (score 0):

You insert separators in menus when you insert a normal menu item with a hyphen "-" as text.

Windows will automatically expand them to separators.

Comment: Initially, I also believed that this was the kind of separators he was looking for. Rather evil to give you a -1, for your response was posted prior to the clarification.